# Direct Users to a link for SSO

Tags: force.com, single-sign-on

I'm trying to share a public calander with people in my org, and not everyone is using SSO (even though they are set up to have SSO!). What i want to do is give them a link to the calander and have it go through the SSO link. I tried `https://SSO_LINK?saveURL=/00130000000EY3n` but you seem to lose the paramater this way during the SSO process.

Any ideas/workarounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this using the startURL parameter.

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sso_provider_addl_params_start.htm&language=en_US

Comment: perfect! thanks. what's the diff between startURL and saveURL?